# How do I get vertical space next to a wrapfigure?

Tags: memoir, wrapfig

I don't understand why commenting and uncommenting the line with the period <.> causes the spacing to move from above the wrapped figure to next to it.

I want the space next to it.

I Have only been able to get what I want with the period.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{img/}}

\begin{document}% document begins
  %
\subparagraph{Download the Forfeiture Field Map}There are 3 different versions %of the map

.% With this line commented, The wrapped text and figure is spaced down 3 in.  %But if its active, just the text is spaced down 3 in(This is the desired %behaviour).

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{CollectorChooseMap.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\vspace{3in}

Push Download

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is impossible to test your example, could you demonstrate the effect using `example-image` which is available for tests? it isn't clear why you are using wrapfig, you only appear to have the two words "Push Download" so it isn't clear how you can have a cutout paragraph that wraps around the figure???? the issue with the `.` is that you are using an run-in section heading that is added to the first line of the paragraph, but without the `.` you have no paragraph after the heading just the figure.

Comment: @Phelype If you compile the code and save the image locally and rename it CollectorChooseMap.png it should compile.  I need the space next to the image and then the  word download.  Experimenting with the line with the period results in different placements of the space.  The word download is the paragraph that I need to wrap the image with.

Comment: @BryanM, I might be wrong, but I think you meant to ping DavidCarlisle in your comment above, didn't you?

Comment: @David Carlisle

Comment: Yes i did  sorry about that Phelype